# JavaScript: onresize won't find my observers array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following code is working fine, but not if I use a method together with an onresize event.

```
function TableUtil() {
    this.observers = [],
    this.addObserver = function(tableSelector) {
         this.observers.push(tableSelector);
    },
    this.notifyObservers = function() {
         console.log('notify observers invoked');
         for (var i in this.observers) {
               this.resize(this.observers[i]);
         }
    },
    // ...

var tableUtil = new TableUtil();
```

tableUtil.notifyObservers() is invoked by following line:

```
$(window).resize(tableUtil.notifyObservers);
```

**BUT** does never call `resize(...)`. If I invoke `tableUtil.notifyObservers()` manually it works.

The problem is that the `observers` array is empty but not if I check in the console.

I have already tried variants with and without jQuery. The problem exists in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass the `notifyObservers` reference to the `resize()` function, the object reference is lost, so inside notifyObservers `this` points to something else. Try this instead:

```
$(window).resize(function() { tableUtil.notifyObservers(); });
```

Comment: An alternative could be to use `var self = this;` in the `TableUtil` constructor, and use `self` where `this` is used.